# What does xp_qv do in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

Last night one of our SQL servers developed some major problems and after a colleague stopped, started, and all the usual things it started checking and rebuilding databases and is now running an extended stored procedure called "xp_qv".

The internet seems to be very short of information on what this procedure does or anythign like that so I was hoping somebody here might be able to help.

I should add that I assume it is meant to be running so the question isn't "Can I stop it" or anything like that, its just curiosity in what it is doing in the hope that it will help determine how long before things are usable again...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the only information I could find..

> xp_qv, hosted in xpsqlbot.dll is a
>   wrapper around functionality in
>   sqlboot.dll, which returns information
>   about the SKU type, licensing etc It
>   is not documented that is why you can
>   not find a reference.

Comment: I'd seen that but my colleague had implied that it was running far more than I'd expect given that explanation. Thanks for the google though. :)